# Lamb Slaughter Recordings. . . 

Tags: animals

Hello all,

I'm trying to design a lamb sacrifice cue and was wondering if anyone knows of any preexisting recordings

Thanks,
Jeremy Bloom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HI there

I mixed a documentary for Discovery about 10 years ago where a zulu tribe sacrificed a goat / lamb for spiritual cleansing in the mountains around Kwazulu Natal South Africa .The noises of the animal shouting , almost crying was overpowering to any cutting / stabbing noises. I think i still have those cries. i will check tomorrow when at work .

Regards

Mark Buyskes

Comment: lordy.  I'll bet you can't fake THAT.

Comment: Gotta love SSD.

Comment: Okay, this is pretty astounding.

Comment: Hi there 
Sorry for late response but have been searching high and low , but with no luck. seems i didnt add the sound into the library , go figure.


Answer (score 0):

Hi Jeremy

Rob Nokes made some great recordings. You can find them on my site. There are some nice foleys with blood and flesh.
https://www.soundeffects.ch/surround-sound-effects-_e.php?soundeffects=flesh

https://www.soundeffects.ch/surround-sound-effects-_e.php?soundeffects=flesh&Category=Horror

https://www.soundeffects.ch/surround-sound-effects-_e.php?soundeffects=animal&Category=Animal,%20Goat

Also check the 'horror' category: https://www.soundeffects.ch/soundeffects/sound-effects-categories/sound-effects-horror.php

Of course it depends if you need it for documentary or more like a horror movie. But also maybe you can find some pig-screams, pitch it up a little and it sounds quite awful.

Best
Guido